# Common Elements Sequence

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two arrays of integer type.

```
int[] righttarray=new int[] {6,9,8,1,5,3};
int[] leftarray=new int[] {1,3};
```

Now I have to find out the common elements between these two as well as I need to match common elements indexes. If the indexes are same then its ok, if not then sequence will be maintained from rightarray.

I am getting Common elements by intersect method in C#.

See, element 1 and 3 are common in both the arrays. But in "leftarray" their sequence in 0,1 and in "rightarray" their sequence in 3,5. How to check this is my question. Thanks !!

Help me out doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try something like:

```
int[] righttarray = new int[] { 6, 3, 8, 1, 5, 3 };
int[] leftarray = new int[] { 1, 3 };

if (righttarray.Length < leftarray.Length)
{
    var result = righttarray.Where((x, i) => righttarray[i] == leftarray[i]);
}
else
{
    var result = leftarray.Where((x, i) => leftarray[i] == righttarray[i]);
}
```

This will give you the number 3, which is in the same index and with the same element number. In your example, the output will be empty, I have changed only to check it ;)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to remove it. I was using Select instead of Where, and I forgot to remove when I change for Where

Comment: Hi !! Oscar Bralo, I have checked your code, but I don't need that. Please see the question again, I have changed a little bit. If you can help me then it will be my pleasure

Comment: Oh, right will be allways longer than left, ruight? "If the indexes are same then its ok, if not then sequence will be maintained from rightarray." I dont aunderstand this, you mean that if all index aren´t equal, you will return right array?

Comment: See, Size can differ, can same in size also. The arrays I have written over is basically the elements of the arrays but if you see this then you will find that index for common elements 1 and 3 differs. In the "rightarray" their indexes are 3,5 where as in "leftarray" their indexes are 0,1 Now if the indexes for all the common elements are same with each other then nothing to do. If not then based on the "rightarray"'s index of common element I will write it to the database. Leftarray is coming from database. And rightarray is coming from view.